# ¿Cuáles son los errores de este código?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
# include <string>

using namespace std;
int main ()



{
  int n1, n2 ,n3 ,n4 , n5;
    float promedio;
    cout <<"ingrese numero 1";
    cin<< n1;
   cout <<"ingrese numero 2";
   cin<< n2;
    cout <<"ingrese numero 3";
    cin<< n3;
     cout <<"ingrese numero 4";
    cin<< n4;
     cout <<"ingrese numero 5";
    cin<< n5;
    promedio=(n1+ n2+ n3+ +n4 +n5)/5;
    cin<<"el promedio es"<<promedio;
    if (promedio < 7) {
            cout<<"aprobado"


    }{else
    cout<< "desaprobado"
    }

   return 0;
}
```

me marca error en esto

```
13:32: error: expected primary-expression before ';' token

14:8: error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}' and 'int')
14:8: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/string:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39,
                 from 2:
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cin<<"el promedio es"<<promedio; esto no deberia ser cout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo muchos errores de sintaxis en tu código. Para empezar hay que definir que son los **flujos de entrada y salida** de c++. Los flujos son secuencias de bytes.

Existen operaciones para llevar a cabo esas acciones.

Por ejemplo, en tú código estas usando **cout** que es un **flujo de salida estandar** y la forma de escribirlo es la correcta como tu código describe.

Sin embargo en el **flujo de entrada** estás haciendo mal uso del operador de extracción.

Cuando son datos de entrada se escribe así:

```
cin>> n1;
```

Con el doble signo mayor. Nótese que es diferente al << del flujo de salida.

Ahora en el segmento `cin<<"el promedio es"<<promedio;` no estoy muy seguro de lo que pretendías hacer, pero si era imprimir el promedio, como es un flujo de salida se utiliza **cout** en vez de **cin**.

```
cout<<"el promedio es: "<<promedio<<endl;;
```

En el segmento de los if-else, te hacen falta las comas de cierre en los cout y estás haciendo mal uso de las llaves. Las llaves de abertura van después de la palabra reservada else

```
    if (promedio < 7) {
            cout<<"aprobado"         //Falta punto y coma
    }{else                           //La llave de abertura se escribe después de else
    cout<< "desaprobado"             //Falta punto y coma 
    }
```

Con todo esto arreglarías tus problemas que se muestra en consola. Saludos.

Comment: Se te ha olvidado comentar que tiene dos sumandos consecutivos: `n3+ +n4` y que para que el promedio salga con decimales hay que usar `5.0f` en vez de `5`